# No /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/CLR on my system?

Tags: linux, kernel, binfmt

I run docky which is programmed with `mono` so I think the binfmt is running correctly, but `proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.automount` complains about it, since I don't have `/proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/CLR`

I already have `CONFIG_BINFMT_MISC=y` in my kernel config.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/CLR` gets created by the kernel when you register a binary format that you've named "CLR". Are you able to register one manually?

```
echo ':CLR:M::MZ::/usr/bin/mono:' | sudo tee /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/register
```

If this works, then the solution is probably that you should add a file in `/etc/binfmt.d`; see `man binfmt.d` for more information.

Are you sure systemd is complaining about it not already being there? systemd's `systemd-binfmt.service` is supposed to do that for you (but I think it does need that config file in order to do it).

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I thought CLR was a standard interface that means something ... And the problem is that I disabled auto-mount in kernel, now it's resolved